# Numeric textbox C# accepts only 4 digits

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I want to create numeric textbox for numbers and string using c# code.

How to do the numeric textbox accepts only 4 digitd in c#?-WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF TextBox has a MaxLength property which restricts the input length, e.g.

```
this.textBox1.MaxLength = 4;
```